# Can state parameter alone provide sufficient protection for OIDC with a confidential client?

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect, openid

In poring over the OIDC spec and numerous implementation guides and articles, I still haven't been able to definitively determine whether the `state` parameter alone can provide sufficient protection for my particular OIDC use case, though it seems it should be. Given that I am using:

- The authorization code flow
- An auth server which disallows re-use of codes
- A confidential client (using a client secret to authenticate itself with the auth server)
- A cryptographically secure, random `state`, stored in the user's session

is there any attack for which additional measures (`nonce` or PKCE) provide additional protection? It seems to me that the following are covered:

##### CSRF Attack

An attacker authenticates using her own account, gaining an authorization code, then tricks the user into visiting the client's redirect endpoint using her code, logging the user into her account. This scenario is prevented: the client compares `state` in the user's session (if any) to `state` in the request, finds a mismatch, and rejects the request.

##### Code Replay Attack

After a user has logged in, an attacker gains access to their authorization code (by, e.g., inspecting browser history on a shared machine), then uses that code with the client's redirect endpoint to trigger a token exchange, logging the attacker into the user's account. This scenario is prevented: the user has previously exchanged the code for a token, and the auth server will not allow it to be reused.

##### MITM Attack

An attacker is able to read plaintext traffic between the user agent and the client or the auth server (e.g. malware, corporate networks which break TLS). This scenario is **unable to be mitigated**, as an attacker would be privy to all information necessary to recreate the user's session on their own machine.

Is my understanding correct in all of the above?

Answer (score 3):

One problem with the **state** parameter alone is that it is a **client side** validation and it is up to each client to verify this parameter. However, not every client performs this validation and that is a problem.

by adding **PKCE**, we get a **server-side** validation and that means that badly implemented clients will not be able to authenticate and the identity provider can enforce/require that **PKCE** is used.

Comment: For confidential clients PKCE is not that crucial - it's much more difficult to use a stolen authorization code when you have a confidential client. Still, if it is possible it's better to use PKCE than not.

Comment: I recently blogged about the state and nonce parameter here:
* Demystifying OpenID Connect’s State and Nonce Parameters in ASP.NET Core - https://nestenius.se/2023/12/13/demystifying-openid-connects-state-and-nonce-parameters-in-asp-net-core/